# Need to reboot twice when Ubuntu 12.04.1 mdadm RAID1 degraded

Tags: 12.04, raid, mdadm

I'm testing mdadm RAID1. 
I'm using two HDD. 
Created / (/dev/md0 with /dev/sda1 and /dev/sdb1) and 
swap (/dev/md1 with /dev/sda5 and /dev/sdb5)
After OS installed. I removed one HDD and reboot the system.
The system show black screen (after GRUB boot loader loaded).
I need to force shutdown the system and restart again. Then the system can boot into OS.
I tried several times. It's all the same. I need to reboot twice.
Is that normal?

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 aspects to your issue:

1. When you create the RAID you are eventually asked if you want to *boot in degraded mode*. I suppose you answered with *yes*
2. Even when *boot degraded* is enabled it takes some time - I had the same feeling you had just now but was more patient it seems :-), so please wait a while (the system appears to not do anything at all - I suppose it is waiting for the second drive to "wake up").